# What is the exact meaning of ViewModel syntax? (about Kotlin syntax, Jetpack Compose)

Tags: kotlin, syntax, android-jetpack-compose

Doing jetpack compose codelab(state), In ViewModel there's something Can't make sense I think.
And I'm so confused that have some questions. Here is codes from codelab

**VieModel**

```kotlin
class TodoViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private var _todoItems = MutableLiveData(listOf<TodoItem>())

    val todoItems: LiveData<List<TodoItem>> = _todoItems

    // ...
}
```

**First**
Here is my thought.
`todoItems` is variable that contains MutableLiveData which contains list of TodoItems.
And `todoItems` is value that have type `LiveData<List<TodoItem>>` and contain `_todoItems`
In this flow, why `todoItems` has that type?
Why the first type from `MutableLiveData(listOf<TodoItem>())` is equivalent to `LiveData<List<TodoItem>>`?

**Second**
Second questions is about using that viewmodel with variable.
here is codes.

```kotlin
@Composable
private fun TodoActivityScreen(todoViewModel: TodoViewModel) {

    val items: List<TodoItem> by todoViewModel.todoItems.observeAsState(listOf())

    TodoScreen(
        items = items,
        onAddItem = { todoViewModel.addItem(it) },
        onRemoveItem = { todoViewModel.removeItem(it) }
    )
}
```

`items` from ViewModel is just `List<TodoItem>`.
And Why the type returned to `List<TodoItem>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question,
We want to update the list of `TodoItem` that's why we need a `MutableLiveData`. But we don't want to expose this mutable property to outside world as no one outside view model should be able to modify this list. So we expose a `LiveData` which is immutable. Since `MutableLiveData` extends `LiveData` we can directly assign `_todoItems` to `todoItems`.

For your second question,
`observeAsState` is an extension function on `LiveData` which converts it to a `State`, in your case `State<List<TodoItem>>`. `by` is used to unwrap the `State` and directly access the `List<TodoItem` which is then supplied to `TodoScreen`. Whenever the value of `todoViewModel.todoItems` changes, `items` will be initialised with new value and `TodoActivityScreen` will get recomposed.

Comment: It does helpful for understanding. thank you. How can I know these details about jetpack compose? Is this just conventional usecase?

Comment: You can go through the official Compose [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tutorial) and [docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state). They are really good.